# How do I differentiate between Android and iPad with media query?

Tags: iphone, android, html, css, media-queries

In a page I'm making, I'm writing a secondary stylesheet for mobile devices that overwrites selected parts of the first stylesheet.

I'm using media queries in the following way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/ui.css">
<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/ui_mobile.css" type="text/css">
```

This works for iPhone.  My goal is to create a query that will activate if it's an iPhone or Android, and then let the iPad use the standard desktop styling.

When I switch it to max-device-width: 800px, it triggers on the iPhone and Android, but also triggers on iPad.  It should not be doing this, as the max-device-width of the iPad is allegedly 780px.  But it is, for whatever reason.

I've used many permutations of various widths, heights, and aspect ratios, but to no avail.  Does anyone know a workable way of differentiating between these three?

Any suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: This link https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/  will be help you out  to  achieve that

Answer (score 2):

> When I switch it to max-device-width: 800px, it triggers on the iPhone and Android, but also triggers on iPad. It should not be doing this, as the max-device-width of the iPad is allegedly 780px. But it is, for whatever reason.

I think you're misunderstanding how `max-device-width` works. Since the `max-device-width` of an iPad is 780px, it falls below the 800px limit just as validly as the iPhone does.

Comment: I see.  Does max-device-width trigger if the maximum width of the device's screen falls below the given value?

Answer (score 0):

Try using physical measurements rather than pixels - what you are trying to do is restrict to small screens, independent of resolution. Try

```
max-device-width:12cm
```

Which will only match physically small screens, like a phone (no matter how high resolution), but not larger ones like tablets, regardless how the resolutions change in the future.